# How do I find the largest x,y and smallest x,y in a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, dart

`List<List<double>> intArr = [[448.0, 392.5], [465.5, 392.5], [493.5, 388.0], [536.0, 383.0], [609.5, 374.0], [667.5, 371.5], [714.5, 370.0], [771.0, 375.0], [804.0, 387.5], [821.0, 409.0], [828.0, 434.5], [833.0, 471.5], [834.0, 511.0], [833.0, 546.5], [829.5, 607.5], [819.5, 650.0], [804.5, 697.0], [799.5, 721.0], [796.5, 737.0], [795.0, 746.0], [792.5, 757.5], [791.0, 765.0]]`

> The above is my 2D ours. I want to find the smallest x and smallest y in this array and keep it as 2 in a new array. How can I do it. I am sharing a piece as an example below.
>
> List<List> newList [[834,757.5],[448,370]]

```
 List biggestPair = intArr[0];
List smallestPair = intArr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
  List pair = intArr[i];
  if (pair[0] >= biggestPair[0]) {
    if (pair[1] < biggestPair[1]) {
      continue;
    }
    biggestPair = pair;
  } else if (pair[0] < smallestPair[0]) {
    if (pair[1] > smallestPair[1]) {
      continue;
    }
    smallestPair = pair;
  }
}
newArr = [biggestPair, smallestPair];
print(newArr);
```

> The above code does not give the exact result I want. The above code gives the following result, but this result is wrong.
> [[834.0, 511.0], [448.0, 392.5]]

Comment: Can I just ask why you are not using the `Point` class from `dart:math` to represent each point instead of wasting memory on allocating a list for each point? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-math/Point-class.html

Comment: All of these data are coming from mqtt instantly. It is calculated, reduced to 2 parts and processed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your code is not working as intended is because what you want is not part of your existing set of points since your result is actually a new generated point where you combine data from other points.

But in your code you are doing `biggestPair = pair;` and `smallestPair = pair;` where you save points form your list of points and uses that as result.

I would rewrite the code into something like this making use of `dart:math`:

```
void main() {
  var maxX = intArr[0][0];
  var maxY = intArr[0][0];
  var minX = intArr[0][1];
  var minY = intArr[0][1];

  for (final pair in intArr) {
    final x = pair[0];
    final y = pair[1];

    maxX = max(maxX, x);
    maxY = max(maxY, y);
    minX = min(minX, x);
    minY = min(minY, y);
  }
  final result = [[maxX, maxY], [minX, minY]];

  print(result); // [[834.0, 765.0], [392.5, 370.0]]
}
```